# RigidBody clipping through Walls (PHYSICS)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, controller, move, physics

Now I know this post has been covered numerous times but the solutions found on the posts were:

Ensure your collider isnt a trigger

Make sure your player model and collider are the same size

Set collision detection to 'Continuous Dynamic'

These do not work for me.
I am starting to believe it is to do with my code rather than the colliders themselves.

https://streamable.com/9jzh3g
As seen by the video, there are many... MANY clipping issues.

Here is my controller:

```
    void Update()
    {
        RaycastHit hit;
        if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, Vector3.down, out hit, raycastDist, groundLayer))
            isGrounded = true;
        else
            isGrounded = false;
 
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, angle, 0);
        float horizontalInput = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
 
 
        angle -= horizontalInput * angleSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
 
        Vector3 newPosition = Quaternion.Euler(0, angle, 0) * new Vector3(0, 0, radius);
 
        newPosition.y = rb.position.y; // leave Y unchanged to allow for jumps
        rb.position = newPosition;
 
        //jump
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && isGrounded)
        {
            Debug.Log("Jumping");
            rb.AddForce(Vector3.up * jumpForce, ForceMode.Impulse);
        }
    }
```

I was told that it is due to the position being based on angle and I was given this feedback:
`Oh, because your position is based on 'angle' and even if the rigidbody changes position to avoid colliding the angle stays the same so the next frame it gets set back to inside the collider.

What you want to do is check your angle around the cylinder at the start of FixedUpdate or something and then set the 'angle' variable to that so when the rigidbody moves out for a collider the angle also updates. You should also update the angle variable inside of FixedUpdate so you don't get jittering when colliding too.`

I do not know how to work on this feedback and re-write this code without it breaking
Any suggestions?

Comment: For physics in unity, use `FixedUpdate`, not `Update`.  From [Docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.FixedUpdate.html): `Use FixedUpdate when using Rigidbody.`

Comment: It's difficult to directly move a rigidbody while still respecting collisions. Have you considered completely relying on the physics system in Unity, and manipulating the player's velocity instead? Essentially, you'd want to adjust the player's velocity to create [circular motion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_motion). You'll add velocity in the direction of the center of the tower, while also adding velocity perpendicular to it (based on if the player is moving forward/backward).

Answer (score 0):

Use `Rigidbody` movers instead of direct translation:

```cs
rb.MoveRotation(Quaternion.Euler(0, angle, 0)); // rigid change rotation method 
....
newPosition.y = rb.position.y; // leave Y unchanged to allow for jumps
rb.MovePosition(newPosition); // rigid change position method
```